# Codename one : how to make a customized reception of push notification

Tags: java, push-notification, codenameone

I want to customize codenameone push notifications received on android/iOS devices.

Currently , I'm using the `notifyStatusBar` method, but I don't know what to put in the Hashtable parameter.

```
Display.getInstance().notifyStatusBar("Test notification", "Mobile", value, true, false, new Hashtable());
```

Answer (score 1):

`notifyStatusBar` is just a method to show an alert on status bar of the device your app is running on (only platforms that support it).

Push notification is a pro feature in codename one that allows you to send a remote notification from your app running on one device to the other or from web to your app. Don't confuse the this for local notification.

If you need a local notification, you can do this:

```
LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
n.setId("demo-notification");
n.setAlertBody("It's time to take a break and look at me");
n.setAlertTitle("Break Time!");
n.setAlertSound("beep-01a.mp3");

Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
    n,
    System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, // fire date/time
    LocalNotification.REPEAT_MINUTE  // Whether to repeat and what frequency
);
```

Source above is part of [this blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html).

And You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-push-notification-send-server-push-messages.html) on how to create push notification in codename one, if that's what you're looking for and read about recent changes to push notification [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migration-to-the-new-push-servers-completed.html) and [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-push-servers.html)

By the way, the method you posted above has been deprecated.

Comment: Now I'm able to send notification from a server web to the app , but I want to handle the manner the notification is displayed . LocalNotification ,I think, is not suitable in my case .

Comment: On which platform? Note that the way notifications are shown on iOS devices can be changed on the device by users.

Comment: Now I'm testing on android platform . You said that the method "notifyStatusBar" is deprecated , so which method should I use ?

Comment: The method I posted in the answer has replaced notifyStatusBar. Push notification has it's own internal notifyStatusbar which is called even when the app is running